# Redirecing user to another page using javascript in less time

Tags: javascript

I am checking an user is authenticated or not and if not I am redirecting to new page using javascript. But window.location is taking too long time. So how can I minimize that.
Here is the line I have written

window.location.href=url;

Comment: What if I disable JavaScript? Can I then browse the page even if I'm not authenticated? Always use server-side code for authentication related things

Comment: What do you mean by too long time? Are you sure the url itself is not just taking too long to load?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try with window.location.replace(url), it replaces the current history item, maybe could be faster. location=url will work too.

Comment: Ya location=url is working but I need to do this little faster. Will try with window.location.replace(url) now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If a user does not have access to a certain page, it should be the server's responsibility to prevent them seeing it, not the client.

A good way to do this is to return a response with a [403 status](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) code and HTML that reflects a generic access denied page.

Comment: Yes but my requirement is I need to redirect to another page. I don't have flexibility to write any server side code. I have to do it on client side only.